# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _formik.useFormik)...')

Tags: react-native, expo, formik, yup

I'm trying to implement Formik forms but I encountered the following error.

[image: 1]

And here is the code that I followed(Cloned the project) :- https://github.com/amandeepmittal/react-native-examples/tree/main/forms-with-formik

Answer (score 0):

There is a big chance that there is nothing related to formik, I was getting same error, because I had wrong import path for my globalConfig file.